# Botão para retornar a uma intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Meu problema é: Voltar de uma Activity para uma intent.

Tenho a seguinte sequencia de paginas:

```
-MainActivity
-Intent(Escolher foto)
-DadosActivity
```

Na MainActivity eu tenho um botão para abrir uma intent para que o usuário selecione uma foto, com o seguinte código:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

if (i.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

    startActivityForResult(i, SELECAO_GALERIA);

}
```

Nessa intent o usuario irá selecionar uma foto e após isso é enviado esse item selecionado para outra pagina, através desse código:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == MainActivity.this.RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap image = null;

        try {

            switch (requestCode) {

                case SELECAO_CAMERA:

                    image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    break;

                case SELECAO_GALERIA:

                    Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();

                    image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), localImagemSelecionada);

                    break;

            }

            if (image != null) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
                byte[] dadosImagem = baos.toByteArray();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DadosPostagemActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("fotoEscolhida", dadosImagem);
                startActivity(i);


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

Na ultima activity, DadosActivity, o usuario poder fazer algumas alterações na imagem, porem o meu problema está ao pressionar o botão da back do dispositivo e/ou o da toolbar, com o seguinte código:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_dados);
toolbar.setTitle("Adicione uma descrição");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

De acordo com o que eu fiz no AndroidManifest

```
<activity
android:name=".activity.DadosPostagemActivity"
android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
```

a Activity está voltando para a MainActivity, porem eu queria q ao pressionar-lo voltasse na intent e pudesse escolher novamente a imagem.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer isso, para que ao invés de voltar a MainActivity, voltar para a intent para que ele possa escolher novamente a imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal sobrescrever o método `onBackPressed()` na `DadosActivity` e colocar ali novamente a chamada para o `Intent`? Este método é chamado quando você pressiona voltar e por padrão ele finaliza a Activity atual. Como está voltando para a sua primeira, significa que o `Intent` não entra na pilha de `Activities`, portanto não teria como voltar a ele naturalmente, sem uma nova chamada.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed(); //comportamento padrão - finaliza Activity atual
    //chamada para o Intent
}
```

Edit: Para reutilizar código como você perguntou nos comentários, a opção mais simples seria você criar uma classe com o código que é utilizado pelas duas `Activities` e reutilizar. Porém se você quiser aproveitar o código da `MainActivity` será necessário algumas mudanças. Você teria que receber uma mensagem da `DadosActivity` quando você voltasse e fazer um tratamento para quando receber essa mensagem fazer direto o código de escolher imagem. Para isso utilize `startActivityForResult` para chamar a `DadosActivity` e na `DadosActivity` você usa `setResult` com um código especifico. Na `MainActivity` no método `onActivityResult`, que é retornado após finalizada a `DadosActivity` no voltar, você trata esse código e faz a chamada do `Intent` para a escolha de foto. Da um trabalhinho mas acho q vai ficar melhor.

Comment: Vou testar aqui e te dou um retorno! Vlww

Comment: O unico problema q encontrei e que, vou precisar fazer novamente os código que passam a imagem escolhida para a tela de DadosPostagem. Caso tenha uma maneira de voltar a MainActivity porem com o botão já a intent de action_pick já aberta ai n precisa refazer esses código. teria algum jeito?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Vê se atende ao que você precisa!